# How to read all messages from kafka using segmentio/kafka-go?

Tags: go, apache-kafka, batch-processing

I run the example from the package documentation `segmentio/kafka-go`, but in it I get 1 message at a time.

Is there any way to read all the messages that have accumulated in Kafka at a time and parse them immediately into `[]MyType`?

```golang
func main() {

    // to consume messages
    kafkaBrokerUrl := "localhost:9092"
    topic := "test"

    conn, err := kafka.DialLeader(context.Background(), "tcp", kafkaBrokerUrl, topic, 0)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("failed to dial leader:", err)
    }

    batch := conn.ReadBatch(10e3, 1e6) // fetch 10KB min, 1MB max

    b := make([]byte, 10e3) // 10KB max per message
    for {
        n, err := batch.Read(b)
        if err != nil {
            break
        }
        fmt.Println(string(b[:n]))
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show how do you initialize your consumer?

Comment: @GerardGarcia I added code. I also try `kafka.NewReader` and `ReadMessage`

Comment: Kafka isn't really meant for batch processing. You need to poll the entire topic in a loop and built up your own slice/buffer (don't print each slice, append it to an existing buffer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kafka doesn't help in batch processing , if you mean something like sliding window mechanism to take a batch of streams for a particular time ,size better to use a apache kafka and  apache flink connector , flink provides sliding window mechanism , hdfs storage and moreover flink gives a much better fault tolerance by checkpoints . Unfortunately the flink go sdk available is unstable.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily submit '[]Type' as the message instead of 'Type'
also, decode it as '[]Type'.

```
var ts []Type //data

// encode the data 
var bu bytes.Buffer        
enc := gob.NewEncoder(&bu) 
err := enc.Encode(ts)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("encode error:", err)
}

//Submit the message or messages
msg := kafka.Message{
        Key:   key,
        Value: bu.Bytes(),
    }
kafkaWriter := &kafka.Writer{
    Addr:     kafka.TCP([]string{Broker1}...),
    Topic:    Topic,
    Balancer: &kafka.LeastBytes{},
}
err := kafkaWriter.WriteMessages(ctx,
    msg,
)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
```